# Android load & read properties file in library project

Tags: java, android

I have android & rest webservice api binary project

```
 OnlineCourse
    src
    res
    lib
    manifest.xml


 CourseAPI
     src
     config.properties
     build.xml
```

`Android project right click -> property -> java build path -> project ->Add select CourseAPI project`. That all i did.

My problem is courseAPI project contain property file &  java file read values.When I run only courseAPi project working file , read property file.

But when I run the android project, that binary java file couldn't read file. It say `FileNotFoundException`

Please guide me what is an issue

Answer (score 0):

To read the properties file, you have to put the properties file in main project.